# Matching strings in a bash case statement and finding the current wireless network

Tags: linux, bash, wireless, iwconfig

I've got a bash script (for personal use), part of which prints a message depending on which network I'm connected to. As part of this I want to look at the ID of the currently connected wireless network.

What I'm doing is parsing the wireless name out of the output of `iwconfig` and I want to print out the name, or a special message for certain networks:

```
SSID=`iwconfig wlan0|grep "ESSID:" | sed "s/.*ESSID:\"\(.*\)\"/\1/"` 2>/dev/null
case "$SSID" in
    StaffOnly)
        echo "Staff only network at Work" ;;
    *)
        echo "You're on a wireless network called $SSID"
esac
```

The second part of this (printing the name of whatever network I'm connected to) works, but the special case of being on the StaffOnly network doesn't match and falls through the other one.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong with the `case` statement. And also if there's just a better way of doing this anyway.

Comment: The case looks fine. Check that `$SSID` does not contain any leading/trailing whitespace and that case matches.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. It did indeed have a space on the end. But I can't work out where it came from. Probably to do with my use of `sed`. I've fixed it by appending a `tr -d " "` to that pipeline but it seems a bit hacky.

Comment: The `sed` command should have `.*` _after_ the quote too. Like `"s/.*ESSID:\"\(.*\)".*/\1/"`. Without that the text beyond the end of the quote, which happens to contain some whitespace, will remain there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sed` command lacks trailing `.*`. It should be:

```
SSID=`iwconfig wlan0|grep "ESSID:" | sed "s/.*ESSID:\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/"` 2>/dev/null
                                                              ^^ HERE!
```

Without that you are leaving the end of the line in and it apparently contains some whitespace that's causing mismatch for you.

Several related notes:

- The redirection should go *inside* the backquote:

  ```
  SSID=`iwconfig wlan0|grep "ESSID:" | sed "s/.*ESSID:\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/" 2>/dev/null`
  ```
- `$()` is generally preferred over backquote, because it can nest:

  ```
  SSID=$(iwconfig wlan0|grep "ESSID:" | sed "s/.*ESSID:\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/" 2>/dev/null)
  ```
- When doing debug prints, always add some delimiters around the variable content so you see any leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `sed`. It can all be done using `grep` as follows:

```
SSID=$(iwconfig wlan0 | grep -oP '(?<=ESSID:")[^"]*')
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I knew there was _a_ way to do it with grep but, to be honest, getting into lookbehind and such really hurts my brain! I'll have to have another look at it...